# What's the difference between exchange sort and bubble sort? Are they the same?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I am kind of a noob in algorithm, so I have been doing my research on sorting algorithm. I know Bubble sort has to do with comparing a value with it neighbour and swapping if the one on the left is greater than the right. The complexity is `O(n^2)`. i came across exchange sort and it seems to have the same characteristics and algorithm. I have tried doing my research on exchange sort but the results i get are limited and they kind of contradict. So are they the same?

Is Bubble sort a type of exchange sort or is it the other way around?

If they are different, what characteristic(s) makes them different?

Comment: Perhaps post the pseudocode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only difference is in the way they compare elements, bubble sort passes through list and exchange elements. Exchange sort compares one element with the all other elements.

So when we sort array with bubble sort, we compare array[n] to array[n+1].
With exchange sort, we compare array[1] with array[2],array[3]...array[k] in first pass, then array[2] with array[3],array[4]...array[k] in the second pass etc.

Exchange algorithm visualisation - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0ipy1h-TPM

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Really appreciate thjs.