# What is this inefficient sorting algorithm with two loops that compares the element at each index with all other elements and swaps if needed?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

What type of sort is this? It seems to be not very efficient in sorting, but I cannot find the name for it. Could someone help me out?

```
    for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
        for (int h = k + 1; h < a.length; h++) {
            if (a[k].compareTo(a[h]) > 0) {
                String temp = a[k];
                a[k] = a[h];
                a[h] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The defining characteristic of a bubble sort is that it compares adjacent elements. So no, that is not a bubble sort. It's closer to a selection sort, but it's not a true selection sort either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between exchange sort and bubble sort? Are they the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786409/whats-the-difference-between-exchange-sort-and-bubble-sort-are-they-the-same)

Comment: This is a hybrid variation of bubble sort and selection sort known as an [exchange sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Exchange_sort) which has none of the benefits of either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is named [Exchange sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Exchange_sort) and is sometimes confused with bubble sort. While Bubble sort compares adjacent elements, Exchange sort compares the first element with all the following elements and swaps if needed. Then it does the same for the second element and so on.